# Is it necessary to develop test scripts in the same language as the software for CI, CD?

Tags: java, .net, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, automated-tests

The product is build in vb.net and the test scripts are developed in Java(Selenium) and the CI tool is Jenkins.
So, can there be an issue if we do CI and CD using these platforms.

Comment: When we are running a build can there be an issue in automated test running(using jenkins) after the build is completed?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is not necessary in any way to use the same product development language as used for CI & CD.

By far and away, the **MOST** important thing is to allow CI & CD to occur at all.

After that, the next most important is for CI & CD to be done as quickly and efficiently as possible.  What languages are used to achieve this aren't critical. Putting it another way; Use whatever languages and tools get the job done as efficiently and effectively as possible.  This applies to the product and the automation used to create the product.

For example, I worked on a highly efficient C++ project that used Perl for developing unit tests and Make for executing CI & CD.